# No unique bean of type [] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [dbImpl, DbImpl]

Tags: java, spring

Hi I am new to Spring: I have a problem  related  with the configuration of my project;

this is my servlet-context.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.metmi.mmasgis" />

    <beans:bean id="DbImpl" class="com.metmi.mmasgis.dao.DbImpl">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    </beans:bean>



    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="username" value="root"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="password" value="vilu7240"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springschema">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

this is my controller:

```
    package com.metmi.mmasgis;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.metmi.mmasgis.dao.DbImpl;
import com.metmi.mmasgis.model.Db;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    DbImpl dbs;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG,
                DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate);

        return "home";
    }

    /**
     * get the database list in Mysql
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/db", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String dbs(Locale locale, Model model) {
        ArrayList<Db> dbList = dbs.getDatabases();
        model.addAttribute("dbList", dbList);
        return "dbs";
    }

    /**
     * Simply shows ciao.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ciao", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String ciao(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG,
                DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate);

        return "ciao";
    }

}
```

It is pretty basic, I get this error when I run it on the server:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.metmi.mmasgis.dao.DbImpl com.metmi.mmasgis.HomeController.dbs; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.metmi.mmasgis.dao.DbImpl] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [dbImpl, DbImpl]
```

Comment: Is your class DbImpl annotated with component?

Comment: And you don't have to declare your bena definition with <beans:bean class""/> tag <bean class""/> should be enough you already declare xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `servlet-context.xml` you wrote:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.metmi.mmasgis" />

<beans:bean id="DbImpl" class="com.metmi.mmasgis.dao.DbImpl">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>
```

It registers a `Component` with type of `com.metmi.mmasgis.dao.DbImpl` and name of `DbImpl` from XML configuration, and registers this exact same type, with name of `dbImpl` due to Component Scanning ([autodetected components naming](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-scanning-name-generator)). Just omit the DbImpl bean definition in your config.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Basic issue is there are two beans of same type defined in your spring bean pool. There are two ways to resolve this:

1. As "Khosrow" said, remove **DBImpl** declaration from Spring config XML file.
2. If you are using **@Component** annotation on your **DBImpl** class, then give a value to that annotation (like ***@Component("someOtherDbImpl")***) and then in your autowiring put another annotation; like:

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("someOtherDbImpl")
    DbImpl dbs;
```